# NodeJS - Difference between app.use(function(err, req, res, next){}) and process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){})

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, throw

I'm trying to create an error handler on my node project but I don't understand something.

For thrown error, I can catch from 2 different way :

**process.on()**

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
   // Nothing to do... Client request can't be closed
});
```

**app.use()**

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.send("Humm... To bad !", 500);
});
```

I'm using a function with an RESTful API like that :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // throw new Error("This error is caught by app.use()");
  api.getData(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // throw new Error("This error is caught by process.on()");
    }
    /* Some code here */
  });
});
```

I don't really understand what's the difference between both.. And I don't like the process.on() way, on this catch I don't have access to req and res to send a 500 error page to the client..

Comment: You should pass the error to `next` callback for it to be handled correctly

Comment: Humm.. it's working... but why ? ^^

Comment: Because that's how express handles it

Comment: So I have to try each error to know if I can `throw` it here, or if I have to pass to `next` ?

Comment: And if I pass the error to `next` and I add some code on `/* Some code here */` comment. Like `var data = result.data;` I got an other error cause result is `undefined`...
The next call should stop the function right ??

Comment: Just make it `return next(err)` and you won't get undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process.on() will handle any uncaught error in the process where as app.use is proper way to handle request processing errors. You can also define multiple of such handlers and chain together by calling next(err)

Comment: But why some `throw err` are considerer as uncaught error and other are caught by app.use as a proper way ?

Comment: well all throw err go to handler defined in process.on(...), and if you want then to go the you error handler middleware you should use next(err);